# Why print(70 * (50 / 100)) returns 0?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Why it returns 0?

```
print(70 * (50 / 100));
```

70 * 0,5 = 35

I don't know why this is happening. Or did I make some stupid mistake either ... I don't know

Comment: Two words: integer division.

Answer (score 5):

The `50/100` is a division between **integers**. Since `50<100`, the result is 0 and consequently `70*(50/100)` results in 0.

If you want to avoid this, you have to cast one of them as a `double`.

```
70 * (50 / (double)100)
```

or

```
70 * ((double) 50/ 100)
```

Comment: Yes, and do (70 * (50 / 100D)); to fix the problem

Comment: Thanks :) `print(70 * (50.0 / 100.0))` works perfectly.

Comment: @MateuszGrzonka you are welcome ! I am glad that I helped :)

Comment: Mhm... Better is `print(70 * (50.0 / 100.0))` or `print(70 * (50 / 100D))`?

Comment: Silly question...
Probably just a cosmetic difference ...

Comment: @MateuszGrzonka There isn't any big difference. Just in the first case both nubers are doubles and in the second only the one of then, 100, is double.

Comment: everyone casting to double, whats wrong with the gud ol' float? I always just add an f to avoid integer division print(70 * (50 / 100f))

Comment: @Lestat `double` has greater precision than `float`.

Answer (score 2):

When you divide two integers, the result is always an integer. For example, the result of `7 / 3 is 2`.

So on `50/100 is equal to 0.35` and because you are diving two Integers, it will ignore decimal places so it's gonna be a zero - 0, so computer see it as : (ignoring .35)

`70 * 0 = 0`

P.S

Maybe you could explore little bit about invoking Decimal.Divide, your int arguments get implicitly converted to Decimals so .35 won't be ignored.

You can also enforce non-integer division on int arguments by explicitly casting at least one of the arguments to a floating-point type, e.g.:

```
int a = 42;
int b = 23;
double result = (double)a / b;
```

That's how it comes.. :)

Answer (score 1):

Because `/` will output `int` and not `double` value. The result should be 0.5 and 0 will be taken as `int` then it will be multiplied by 70 and the result will be 0.

You need to make a cast as follows :

```
double x = 50/(double)100 ;
```

Then:

```
print(70 * x);
```

Comment: I've updated my answer!!

Answer (score -3):

`50 / 100` is `0` and `70 * 0` is `0`.

Comment: You have over 200,000 Meaningless Internet Points and this was still the best answer you could give?

Comment: Thank you very much for your constructive criticism and your extensive and detailed explanation about what is wrong with my answer. Unfortunately, I haven't been able to find your superior answer to learn from your experience, would you care to share it?

Comment: Every other answer on this page is more detailed than yours. Yours imparts no explanatory information content what so ever. I thought you would know that already, being a rather...well respected...SO user.

Comment: Agreed, this is a pretty terrible answer.